# Is it proper to implement java.util.Collection for a Grid class structure?

Tags: java, collections, grid

I am currently working on a custom implementation of a Grid class, since I often find myself using grids in a lot of my programs, and it has become more convenient to implement lots of operations in this class than to continually work with 2D arrays or ArrayLists of ArrayLists.

I'm looking at having the Grid class implement the Collection interface from java.util.Collection, but I've run into a few problems with some of the method implementations that make me question whether it would even be proper to implement the interface given the nature of my Grid class.

In particular, the following methods don't seem to have a proper implementation in my Grid:

```
public int size();

public boolean isEmpty();

add(E e)

addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)

boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
```

The reason that many of these don't exactly work in my implementation is because I have decided to make my Grid class size immutable (though not the elements themselves), since shrinking the grid might have unspecified behavior (I was thinking of just chopping off the rows/columns necessary with a warning, though), and because the Grid forces a rectangular size (so jagged row sizes are dealt with by filling in the remaining spaces with `null`).

The add methods are hard to implement because I typically see adding an object to a grid as requiring a coordinate to add it at. I could technically just scan the grid from top to bottom, left to right for the first null square, but that might not be the desired behavior for an end client passing the Grid into a function that only takes Collection objects.

Most of these methods *do* have some form of implementation I can use that would technically work, but they aren't the typical use I see of the Grid class.

Given this, does it make it improper to implement Collection? Or would it be better to just go ahead and implement the odd behavior provided I add Javadoc warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `Collection`, although it isn't a perfect fit. Since your grid is immutable (or is it only the grid size?), just throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` for any mutating call. Whether your `Grid` class *should* implement `Collection` depends on how you imagine it being used. There are pros and cons either way.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to imply that the grid size, not the elements, are immutable.

Comment: @Aargonian - I thought as much. It doesn't change my answer, though.

Comment: I agree, it is better to implement Collection (as well as Serializable), as it would help using it alongside other collections in your app. Semantically, Grid IS a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but too long to write in comment. Wouldn't it be easier to use a `map` of `maps` for your grid (since you already said you tried with lists).

Something like

```
 Map<Integer, Map<Integer, YourCustomObject>> grid= new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, YourCustomObject>>();
```

You could then write methods for adding/removing/etc by abusing the map implementations and the use of keys (since they are unique). Some examples below:

```
public void putYourCustomObject(int x, int y, YourCustomObject obj) {
    if (!grid.containsKey(x)) {
        grid.put(x, new HashMap<Integer, YourCustomObject>());
    }
    grid.get(x).put(y, obj);
}

public boolean yourCustomObjectExists(int x, int y) {
    if (!grid.containsKey(x))
        return false;
    else
        return grid.get(x).containsKey(y);
}

public void removeYourCustomObject(int x, int y) {
    if (grid.containsKey(x)) {
        if (grid.get(x).containsKey(y)){
            grid.get(x).remove(y);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return grid.isEmpty();
}

public int size() {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
        size += grid.get(i).size();
    }
    return size;
}
```

And so on. Just wondering why you wouldn't prefer this method as opposed to having to implement the ones from `Collection`